# How can I view an NSError?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, logging

What's the best way to log an `NSError`?

```
- (void)checkThing:(Thing *)thing withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Gives me a `null` message

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Looking at the [NSError](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation tells me that you'll need to do something like:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

This should then give you human readable output

Comment: Well, he needs to have an error to get a description of, first. And the error's `description` will (currently) at least contain the error's domain and code, which may be more useful in a console log message.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen this function, but I didn't understand why the log was giving me (null).

Answer (score 19):

> ```
> NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
> ```
>
> Gives me a null message

Then `error` is `nil`, not an NSError instance.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I thought I was doing something wrong. What is the best way to log an error then?

Comment: Doesn't he need to dereference the `NSError**` as well?

Comment: The original question didn't have two asterisks. Abizern added the second asterisk; I've rolled back his edit, because I don't think it makes sense for the actual question. If it were a double-asterisk argument, it would generally (esp. for an NSError) be an *output* argument, so the method should not attempt to retrieve an object through that pointer.

Comment: nevan: NSLog, exactly the way you're doing it. You need to have an error to log before you can log an error; your problem (insofar as it's a problem) is that you don't have an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rough method I use to log errors while developing; (Not for Cocoa-touch)

```
// Execute the fetch request put the results into array
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *resultArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (resultArray == nil)
{
    // Diagnostic error handling
    NSAlert *anAlert = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
    [anAlert runModal];
}
```

NSAlert takes care of displaying the error.

Comment: Of course, that's only useful on the Mac. UIKit doesn't have NSAlert.

Comment: Yeah! I didn't read the tags. Thanks for the rollback on the edit. I still think this answer is useful to leave up for others, as long as they take note it's only for the desktop.